# How can i retrieve the instance id of an instance that is part of an auto scaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have this bash script that is trying to return the **stopped** instance Ids of an autoscaling group.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=tag:aws:autoscaling:groupName,Values=devASG-123" --query "Reservations[].Instances[?State.Name==stopped].InstanceId" --output text --profile dev
```

This keeps returning a blank value even though I have instances that are stopped

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
aws --profile dev ec2 describe-instances --filters \
  "Name=tag:aws:autoscaling:groupName,Values=devASG-123" \
  "Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped" \
  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId
```

or use `regex`

```sh
aws --profile dev ec2 describe-instances --filters \
  "Name=tag:aws:autoscaling:groupName,Values=devASG-123" \
  "Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped" | \
  grep -o '\"i-[0-9a-f]\\+\"' | grep -o '[^\"]\\+'
```

Comment: All this shows is all the details. I want just the instance ids

Comment: Then filter this, for example, with either `jq` or a regex. See the updated answer.